# How to code mp3 file on webp page for Android Froyo 2.2?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have tried HTML 5 tag and that does not work. I have also tried jPlayer and that does not work as well. I need a mp3 player that will play on Froyo 2.2. Any suggestions or direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jPlayer just makes the `<audio>` tag for you, so both of those are attempting to do audio through HTML5, which the FroYo browser does not support (Gingerbread does, though). The easiest way to play the audio would be to make the audio into a Flash video and insert it that way.

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer's default Solution parameter (html5, flash) does not reliably fallback to use its Flash player in Android 2.2 and higher. At least in those versions of Android the device gives jPlayer a false positive indicator that it supports html5 and, so, the Flash fallback is never called. To make jPlayer work for the Android just revers the default order in the Solution parameter to flash, html5. jPlayer then just grabs the Flash player and runs the media.

The iPhone, given that it doesn't support Flash, will simply fail on the Flash parameter and fallback to HTML5 as it should.